# Porque é que o EF Core está a actualizar dados de outras tabelas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**Porque é que o EF Core está a acttualizar dados de outras tabelas?**

Estou a actualizar uma tabela com o EF mas no entanto eu reparo que o EF está a actualizar essa tabela e ainda outras tabelas.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Cor,Porte,Raca,Vacinado,Sexo,TipoAnimal,TipoAnuncio, Id,Descricao,Aprovado,DataPublicacao,Telefone,Email,Idade, Pais, Localidade")] Anuncio anuncio, IEnumerable<IFormFile> Imagens)
 {
    if (id != anuncio.Id)
    {
      return NotFound();
    }
            var anuncioActualizado = await _context.Anuncio.Include(x => x.Cor)
               .Include(x => x.Imagens)
               .Include(x => x.Localidade)
               .Include(x => x.Pais)
               .Include(x => x.Porte)
               .Include(x => x.Raca)
               .Include(x => x.Sexo)
               .Include(x => x.TipoAnimal)
               .Include(x => x.TipoAnuncio)
               .Include(x => x.User)
               .Include(x => x.Vacinado)
               .Include(x => x.Cor).Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstAsync();

            var userid = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            anuncioActualizado.Cor.Nome = _context.Cor.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Cor.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.Porte.Nome = _context.Porte.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Porte.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.Sexo.Nome = _context.Sexo.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Sexo.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.TipoAnimal.Nome = _context.TipoAnimal.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.TipoAnimal.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.TipoAnuncio.Nome = _context.TipoAnuncio.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.TipoAnuncio.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.Vacinado.Nome = _context.Vacinado.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Vacinado.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.Raca.Nome = _context.Raca.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Raca.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.User = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == _userId).First();
            anuncioActualizado.Pais.Nome = _context.Pais.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Pais.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.Localidade.Nome = _context.Localidade.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Localidade.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;
            anuncioActualizado.DataPublicacao = DateTime.Now;
            anuncioActualizado.Descricao = anuncio.Descricao;
            anuncioActualizado.Email = anuncio.Email;
            anuncioActualizado.Idade = anuncio.Idade;


            if (Imagens != null)
            await ActualizarImagemAsync(anuncioActualizado, Imagens);
            try
            {
                _context.Anuncio.Update(anuncioActualizado);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AnuncioExists(anuncio.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Anuncio", "Anuncios", new { id = anuncio.Id }); 
        }
```

> Então eu apenas quero actualizar a entidade Anuncio No entanto esta
>   está a actualizar as outras entidades como "Cor", "Porte" etc

```
 public class Anuncio: Animal
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public TipoAnuncio TipoAnuncio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Aprovado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Telefone { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Pais Pais { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Localidade Localidade { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

 }
```

> As outras entidades estão todas configuradas assim

```
public class Pais
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: explique melhor!

Comment: Quando tento actualizar a entidade Anuncio este actualiza o valor da entidade Pais ou seja País é uma tabela onde os dados não devem ser alterados mas sim consumidos mas por algum motivo quando altero Anúncio este altera o valor de País, imagine que eu tenho 2 países em País Portugal, Brasil, suponha que o Anúncio foi criado com Portugal e altero para Brasil, o que acontece é que ele altera no Anúncio mas também vai na entidade País e coloca onde está Portugal = Brasil ficando assim com dois países Brasil

Comment: Tenta tirar os `.Nome` em todos, exemplo, `anuncioActualizado.Cor = _context.Cor.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Cor.Id).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amadeu, os valores das outras tabelas estão sendo alterados porque você está alterando.

Quando você faz este comando: `anuncioActualizado.Raca.Nome = _context.Raca.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Raca.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;` o Entity faz o *track* da entidade Raca e entende que houve alteração para ela.

Não entendi a necessidade de você ter que setar o nome dessa forma, mas preocupando somente com a questão de não atualizar essas entidades, você pode fazer o seguinte

```
_context.Entry(anuncioActualizado.Raca).State == EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Isso você fará com que o Entity ignore as alterações da entidade `Raca`.

Outra possibilidade é, no momento em que você estiver "alterando" o nome (como nesse comando `anuncioActualizado.Raca.Nome = _context.Raca.Where(x => x.Id == anuncio.Raca.Id).FirstOrDefault().Nome;`) você pode parar o *trackeamento* do Entity:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

Lembre de voltar o *Track* para `TrackAll`:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Usar o NoTracking... Acho que não é uma boa coisa

Comment: Concordo Renan, como é algo que se refere ao contexto, qualquer operação "em cascata" pode ser afetada. Tem que ter cuidado.