# Erro ao realizar Update no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo o seguinte relacionamento entre Agenda e Contato:

- Uma Agenda pode ter N Contatos;
- Um Contato pode estar em N Agendas;

Ou seja tenho um relacionamento de N:M entre as entidades Agenda e Contato;

Ao criar uma Agenda com a lista de contatos a ação de Add do E.F ocorre perfeitamente, mas ao tentar incluir um novo Contato em uma Agenda já criada ocorre que o `SaveChanges`retorna `1` porém na base não há alteração alguma, ou seja, na tabela AgendaContato não é adicionar os `ID`referentes à Agenda e ao novo contato.

Código que adiciona o novo Contato:

```
public BookModel AddNewContact(ContactModel newcontact, Guid bookId)
{
      Contact contact = null;

      var contatoexiste = _contactRepository.Exist(newcontact.contactId);

      if (contatoexiste)
            contact = _contactRepository.Search(x => x.contactId == 
          newcontact.contactId).FirstOrDefault();

      else
      {
          var newcontactdomain = Mapper.Map<Contact>(newcontact);

         contact = _contactRepository.AddOrUpdate(newcontactdomain);
       }

       try
       {
            var book = _bookRepository.GetById(bookId);

            book.Customers.Add(contact);

            _bookRepository.Update(book);

            return Mapper.Map<BookModel>(book);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

  }
```

Código do Update *(Repositório)*:

```
public T Update(T entity)
{
     _Dbset.Attach(entity);

      Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

      var result = Context.SaveChanges(); //retorna 1 se ok 

      return entity;
}
```

Comment: _BookRepository.GetByIdNotracking(guid) está de fato usando AsNoTracking?

Comment: editei a pergunta e adicionei o código do repositório que faz o `AsNoTracking`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388416/porque-%c3%a9-que-o-ef-core-est%c3%a1-a-actualizar-dados-de-outras-tabelas